# Include dynamic Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

[image]

I have the following relationship in my database, a `product` has several `presentaciones_prouduct`, and in my query I need to include them only if it has at least one product-presentation, for this purpose and created a boolean attribute `lista_precios` in the `product` table, as an indicator, this will handle internally.

Make the following query, to include the list, but it takes a long time, and I have several products that do not need it :

```
var producto = await _context.Producto
                             .Select(x => new
                                          {
                                              x.Id,
                                              x.Nombre,
                                              x.NombreSecundario,
                                              x.MarcaId,
                                              x.IdCategoria,
                                              x.IdUnidad,
                                              x.Precio,
                                              x.PrecioCompra,
                                              x.Codigo,
                                              x.CantidadInicial,
                                              x.CantidadMinima,
                                              x.ListaPrecios,
                    Include------------>      x.PresentacionesProducto,
                                              x.Descripcion
                             }) 
                             .AsNoTracking()
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id== IdProducto);
```

Now I try to cause the least overhead in the system, only including the list if any product has it, this dynamically

```
 if (producto.ListaPrecios) {}
```

**Question:** How would the most efficient consultation in this case be, include the product presentations only if you had them

Answer (score 1):

How about that: x.PresentacionesProducto.Where(p=>producto.ListaPrecios)

With your code:

```
            var producto = await _context.Producto
                         .Select(x => new
                                      {
                                          x.Id,
                                          x.Nombre,
                                          x.NombreSecundario,
                                          x.MarcaId,
                                          x.IdCategoria,
                                          x.IdUnidad,
                                          x.Precio,
                                          x.PrecioCompra,
                                          x.Codigo,
                                          x.CantidadInicial,
                                          x.CantidadMinima,
                                          x.ListaPrecios,
                                          PresentacionesProducto = x.PresentacionesProducto.Where(p=>producto.ListaPrecios),
                                          x.Descripcion
                         }) 
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id== IdProducto);
```

Comment: This is quite close to what I was looking for, but is there a way to call include outside the select? because the search is delayed that way

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to get that one element from db(if exist), and after load navigation property if necessary.

Code:

```
var producto = await _context.Producto
                    .AsNoTracking() //Maybe it is not need
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == IdProducto);

if(producto != null && producto.ListaPrecios)
     _context.Entry<Producto>(producto)
          .Navigation(nameof(producto.PresentacionesProducto))
          .Load();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but explain what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Don't post a comment with an explanation, but edit your answer to include that explanation.

Comment: I think that my question does not explain to me very well, that query does not bring me anything if it does not have the true field, what I need is always to bring the product and dynamically include the list if it has at least one

Comment: Okay, i understand you problem. I modify my answer